# Linux Centos 6 Some how filtered port 80 + broke Apache 2

Tags: linux, apache, port, centos6

I have magically been able to break port 80 / Apache server when following a guide to install PHPMyAdmin (http://www.krizna.com/centos/installing-apache2-mysql-server-php-centos-6-lamp/#apache)

Prior to me to starting the guide, Apache 2 was working for me (was able to view pages and see the default blue one)

I followed the guide down to Step 4 under "PHP installation" and went to check the page and I was getting the following error (note: I skipped Mysql installation since I have it already installed and "Testing your page" in the Apache section since I had it working prior).

ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://`192.168.141.22`/

Read Error

The system returned: (104) Connection reset by peer

An error condition occurred while reading data from the network. Please retry your request.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.


Generated Wed, 03 Jul 2013 19:04:56 GMT by tx22rrpep4da (hpm/3.0.55)
```

I tried to uninstall (yum erase) httpd and php and re-install and no success.

I did an nmap and it shows 80/tcp filtered http.

I even disabled/stopped IP tables incase that was the issue, no luck. I have other things like TS3 running on other ports fine.

Restarted the dedicated server.

netstat -tulpn

```
te       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25896/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30033               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2967/./ts3server_li
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2736/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2798/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2873/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2736/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2967/./ts3server_li
tcp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                        LISTEN      2736/named
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2798/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      2736/named
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9987                0.0.0.0:*                               2967/./ts3server_li
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               2736/named
udp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                                    2736/named
```

I had a few other people test the IP in case it was just my connection but they all got the same as well (IP: `192.168.141.22` )

Really hoping I can get this fixed with out doing something over the top like wiping and re-installing centos 6.

Comment: If Apache was working and you followed that guide, which installs Apache, it seems the re-install might have reset some of your config items. Prior to pointed answer, this will take some digging to find out what the issue is. I would start with checking if firewall is blocking(do wget http://localhost, then do telnet localhost 80 and see what you get)

Comment: For wget localhost:

--2013-07-04 00:17:28--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2013-07-04 00:17:28 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

For telnet localhost 80 I get:

[root@ns4007521 ~]# telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 0):

The netstat command is showing that Apache is in-deed listening on the following IP & port:

```
 0 0.0.0.0:80
```

If you want reach Apache in 192... ip, then you need to edit one of the .conf files that has the "Listen" directive(normally in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ports.conf or the main .conf file) and either put in the ip or remove all ips so Apache can listen on all interfaces available in the machine.

Comment: Ok, I removed Listen 0.0.0.0:80 from the httpd.conf (There was no port one)
Reset httpd no luck.

Starting httpd: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Should I set it to port 80?